# Is there a way to check the credentials in WebDav?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, authentication, webdav

I am using webdav to get a list of files, create folders, etc.. which require the user name and password inside the request.  (all working well)
But I want to know if there is a way to perform only log in, without any additional action?
Just to make sure the user name and password are valid, and have access to SharePoint (in my case)
Maybe there is something like getting user's information? just as a test..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HEAD or OPTIONS request for this purpose. Just include the credentials and you'll get a 401 if they're not valid.

Comment: can you please tell us how to do it i  m using https://sabre.io/ this libary for same